# How can I build such button?

Tags: android, user-interface

I need to implement such button for my Android app. It would be great to do this without using full image as button.
I've done almost the same button using `<shape>` with `<gradient>`. The only thing I need is to add bottom blue button shadow and include image.

[image: Button]

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the quickest way is to use 9-patch image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by combining Shape Drawables inside a Layered Drawable. To do so, you'll have 3 xml files as below:

- button.xml (the one you already have i guess)

  ```
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle" >

      <corners android:radius="16dp" />

      <gradient
          android:angle="270"
          android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
          android:endColor="#CAEBF8"
          android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
          android:type="linear" />

      <padding
          android:bottom="8dp"
          android:left="8dp"
          android:right="8dp"
          android:top="8dp" />

      <stroke
          android:width="2dp"
          android:color="#FFFFFF" />

  </shape>
  ```
- button_bg.xml (to add the blue border below the button)

  ```
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle" >

      <corners android:radius="16dp" />

      <solid android:color="#6FC8F1" />

  </shape>
  ```
- layered_button.xml (to combine the previous xml, and the drawable to use as background on your button)

  ```
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

      <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg"/>
      <item
          android:bottom="2dp"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button"/>

  </layer-list>
  ```

You'll find more information on the Layer List in the [Drawables Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)

Answer (score 1):

Make your button's `android:background` attribute to point your desired image. Create your image with the text and the little person icon. It's not possible to put a text and an image at the same time inside a button.

For the blue shadow, you can either include it in your image or achieve the same result with the gradient attribute as you already said in your question.

Comment: You can put a text and an image inside a button, it's called a Compound View, in which you have a android:drawableLeft attribute (also top, bottom and right) to add an image to the left (and respectively the other directions) of the text. This can help add an icon in an EditText, or as in the example an image in the button

Comment: Thanks for the info, please explain your downvotes from now on.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I guess that your answer was not relevant for the author (he is using xml drawables, which can be reused for severall buttons, so creating plain image would not be suitable for him)

Comment: then who's that sneaky person.. =(

Answer (score -1):

For the image, you should use

```
android:drawableRight
```

As for the shadow I'm not sure how this is achieved.